# Array vs string declaration in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a simple problem with my Ionic app.

So I have this code:

```
export class HomePage {
  devices: string[];
  stuff: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { };

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.devices.push('Roletor3000');
    this.stuff = 'test';
  }
}
```

And for some reason I get an error that `this.devices` does not exist. But `this.stuff` works just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate your array like so:

```
export class HomePage {
  devices: string[] = [];
  stuff: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { };

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.devices.push('Roletor3000');
    this.stuff = 'test';
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks. Still lost with TypeScript a bit. Will select as best in 12 min

Comment: Glad i could help!